# Matching individual points in two different sets of coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, pattern-matching

I have to match some 2d sets of points to an another 2d set of points (as ground truth) and find the outliers. In other word I have to match each single point to (maximum) one of the points in the ground truth set.

As an example consider that I want to match each star of **Ursa Minor**, to one of **Ursa Major's** stars, but in a situation that one of them may have 8 stars and the other one has 7 stars. How could I catch that unmatchable point (the 8th one)?

I found out that Ransac is a good method for matching points but (as I'm using the opencv's function) it needs the two input sets to have equal sizes! which mine don't.

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE. I removed the tag [tag:matching-theory], which is for matchings in graphs. Please read the tag summary when you use a tag.

Comment: If you're really only dealing with set sizes on the order of $7$ or $8$, you can do the match for each of the sets you get by removing one point; the quality of the match (as measured e.g. by the RMS deviation) should be much better if you've removed the outlier than in the other cases.

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the editing. Actually the outlier points may be more than one. I thought that I should find the centroids of two sets and normalize the scales then find the distances, but in this case those outliers effect the centering and so the distances values. How could I find the real centroids of the testing set?